# What is the function of google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I was trying Google maps. I found this statement.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

what is the function of that statement ?

Comment: from the looks of it, it adds a call to "initialize" when the DOM is loaded.

Comment: it runs the function 'initialize' when the window 'load' event is fired?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It adds a listener to the `window` object, which as soon as the `load` event is triggered (i.e. "the page has finished loading") executes the function `initialize`.

I.e. it delays the Google Map related script until the page has finished loading.

Comment: I guess that line could be replaced by `$(document).ready(function() { initialize(); });`?

Comment: Or `$(initialize);`, yes.

Comment: Why isn't it google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'onload', initialize);? I've search all over and I only see 'onload' for use on a DOM object. Is this something that Google has created just for the API? Thanks.

Comment: @GIS Because the event is called "load". The place where you attach the event handler is `.onload`. Google's API wrapper uses the name of the event.

Comment: Not just `load` you can add regular handlers as well (like click  etc.) `google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('btn'),'click',function() { alert('You pressed a button'); });`

Answer (score 1):

@Dust function is initialize and it is called only after the <div> element is loaded.
in maps.event..., I think event is  element because essentially it contains the map-canvas information.