# Updating addDomListener() to addEventListener() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, function, dom

In a callback javascript file that supports a Google map (referenced by the html file) I have used the following Listener code responding to the click event on a checkbox:

```
window.eqfeed_callback = function (results) {
...
...
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("cksites"), 'click', function () {
       ' turn on/off a layer on the map..
    });
...
...
};
```

When inspecting the page I am reminded that "addDomListerner" should be replaced by "addEventListener()" method since the latter is now deprecated (but will still work for the foreseeable future.).

"cksites" is the name of an checkbox that turns on/off a "layer" on the Google map.

A link to update this method is provided in the inspect view.  I've tried numerous combinations of their suggestions and cannot seem to get an updated Listener in place.  I was hoping to save some time as I am not by profession a Google map programmer.

One solution proposed adding:  window.addEventListener("load", initMap); to solve the issue but does not say where in the code this line should be located (near the intiMap line ?)

Any help with this wuold be appreciated (the organization I work with has many of these click events so I thought it best to update them if I could).

Code in use (right now the DomListener event is working but deprecated as mentioned).

1.)  html page which has a Map Menu and the div for the map:

```
 <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
```

2.)   The html page calls a javascript page (in the header) which then loads the map in 2 steps.

function initMap() {
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
zoom: 6,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.59438, -66.15541),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
mapTypeControl: true,
mapTypeControlOptions: {
style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
}
});
// Create a  tag and set the USGS URL as the source.
var script = document.createElement('script');
// This example uses a local copy of theJSON stored at
//script.src = 'https://---------------/scripts/argDataSites.js';
script.src = '../scripts/argDataSites.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}

Note:  The file argDataSites.js is a JSON file with the "site" data inside (id, lat, long, descript, etc).  These values show up in the Google infoWindow.

3.)  Finally a callback function

```
window.eqfeed_callback = function (results) {...};
```

is executed after Map initiation which then reads all of the sites one by one in the argDataSites.js file.  Below this are a number of layers that are turned on/off depending on a checkbox clicked in the Menu overlaying the map.

If more code is needed I can paste here.

Comment: Can you please show the code you wrote but does not work so that we can help you to debug it.

Comment: May assist => https://stackoverflow.com/a/17742391/1533592

Comment: @Rory - if you need more code let me know, I can paste quite a bit more if needed for clarity.